# VBA Paste Calculated Value as Date or Currency

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following vba code to calculate a number from another cell, but when the result is posted in cell B4, it doesn't show a dollar sign currency. I cannot set a range because this is set up to fall on the next available line. I also have a similar calculation that I need shown as a date but it shows as a numerical value.

Sheet2.Range("B4") = Sheet2.Range("B3") * 12

Comment: Add a line underneath like `Sheet2.Range("B4").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub FormatDate()

Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Copy then PasteSpecial once for multiplication and again for formatting.

```
With Sheet2
    .Range("B4") = 12
    .Range("B3").Copy
    .Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
    .Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With
```